Two horizontal bar of Chapters Design in Sonny fncychap coming in Table of Contents
I have the code for table of contents
\documentclass{report}


\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[fill=doc!60,draw=doc!60] (-7,-.1) rectangle (-0.7,.5);%
        \pgftext[left,x=-3.6cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\color{doc!60}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Page \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=doc!60,draw=doc!60] (2pt,0) rectangle (4,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{2pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents*{subsection}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{-1pt}\small}
{}
{}
{\ --- \small\thecontentspage}
[ \textbullet\ ][]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
    \chapter*{%
        \vspace*{-20\p@}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
            \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{doc!60}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
            \draw[fill=doc!60,draw=doc!60] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
            \clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
            \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents 
\pagebreak


\chapter{Ch 1}
\chapter{Ch 2}
\end{document}

With this the table of contents page should coming like this.

But whenever I add \usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap} in the preamble the top block of Contents in the blue box gets vanished and two bars are coming like the picture in the bottom.

Even when I am using any other fncychap styles like Coonny, Glenn it is not getting compiled. How to make the table of contents appear correctly.

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. However,note, that loading fncychap not only changes \chapter but also \chapter*.

What would be the reason for a very peculiar chapter style for the table of contents very different from the style of all other chapters?

Not very peculiar chapter style for other chapter styles the document is not even getting compiled

As already told in a comment, fncychap does not only redefine the formatting of numbered chapter, but also of not numbered chapters. But it seems you want to use the original code for the \tableofcontents.
Although I can't really recommend using a completely different heading style just for the table of contents, you can save the original definition before loading fncychap and restore it locally just for the table of contents:
% DISCLAIMER: I would not recommend to use the following code! It is very ugly style.
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\NewCommandCopy\Original@MakeSchapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\makeatother
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{doc}{RGB}{0,60,110}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0cm}
\titlecontents{chapter}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{30pt}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
        \draw[fill=doc!60,draw=doc!60] (-7,-.1) rectangle (-0.7,.5);%
        \pgftext[left,x=-3.6cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Large\sc\bfseries Chapter\ \thecontentslabel};%
    \end{tikzpicture}\color{doc!60}\large\sc\bfseries}%
{}
{}
{\;\titlerule\;\large\sc\bfseries Page \thecontentspage
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=doc!60,draw=doc!60] (2pt,0) rectangle (4,0.1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\titlecontents{section}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{2pt}}
{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel]{2pc}}
{}
{\hfill\small \thecontentspage}
[]
\titlecontents*{subsection}[3.7pc]
{\addvspace{-1pt}\small}
{}
{}
{\ --- \small\thecontentspage}
[ \textbullet\ ][]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \begingroup
    \RenewCommandCopy\@makeschapterhead\Original@MakeSchapterhead
    \chapter*{%
        \vspace*{-20\p@}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
            \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{doc!60}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
            \draw[fill=doc!60,draw=doc!60] (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);%
            \clip (13,-.75) rectangle (20,1);
            \pgftext[right,x=15cm,y=0.2cm]{\color{white}\Huge\sc\bfseries \contentsname};%
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\pagebreak
\tableofcontents 
\pagebreak


\chapter{Ch 1}
\chapter{Ch 2}
\end{document}


In my opinion, however, it would be better to change the style of all chapters to match each other, for example using the titlesec package or a class such as memoir or scrreprt.
